# How to Display BigCommerce and Deliverr (Flexport) Shipping Options Together in Checkout Page?

Tags: bigcommerce

I've integrated Deliverr (Flexport) with my BigCommerce store to expand my shipping options. However, I'm facing a challenge in displaying both BigCommerce's native shipping options and Deliverr's options simultaneously during the checkout process.

I want to provide customers with a choice between various shipping methods offered by BigCommerce and Deliverr, and I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this. Specifically, I need to ensure that customers can see and select from both sets of shipping options when finalizing their orders.

Here are the main points I'd like assistance with:

1. How can I ensure that Deliverr's shipping options are properly
   integrated and enabled within BigCommerce?
2. What customization steps do I need to take to display both sets of
   shipping options clearly on the checkout page?
3. Are there any specific HTML/CSS modifications or theme customization
   features I should be aware of to achieve this?

Any guidance, code examples, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Feel free to adjust the question as needed to better match your specific situation and requirements. Be sure to provide any relevant details or code snippets to help potential answerers understand your issue better.

here is the Flexport official doc for implementing the shipping options.
(https://tags.deliverr.dev/guide/#displaying-the-offer-at-checkout)